# Spike simulator ISA error - command not found

Tags: instruction-set, spike

having the **spike** file and the **pk** file in a folder, when I run this command in terminal:

```
spike -m128 pk archive.x
```

the following error appears:

```
zsh: command not found: spike
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work on my machine but it works on others.
I already have riscv64 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if *which spike* isn't returning anything, then spike isn't in your path. Also, it might help to build spike with a prefix value like /usr/share/$RISCV so that when you sudo make install, everything gets installed in typical path locations.